# How to integrate ngAA to Laravel jwt-auth

Tags: angularjs, laravel, authentication, jwt

I use [ngAA](https://github.com/lykmapipo/ngAA) to integrate Angularjs and Laravel jwt-auth. In AuthenticateController of Laravel I use this code:

```
public function authenticate(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

        try {
            // verify the credentials and create a token for the user
            if (! $token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)) {
                return response()->json(['error' => 'invalid_credentials'], 401);
            }
        } catch (JWTException $e) {
            // something went wrong
            return response()->json(['error' => 'could_not_create_token'], 500);
        }

        // if no errors are encountered we can return a JWT
        return response()->json(compact('token'));
    }
```

but ngAA in angularjs need to this format for response:

```
{
    token:'your jwt valid token',
    user:{
       .....,
       .....
    }
}
```

How to generate this format of token and user object in Laravel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve problem replace

```
return response()->json(compact('token'));
```

with

```
$user = Auth::User();
return response()->json(compact('token','user'));
```

and don't forget `use App\User;`